# multi level embeds_many works fine on new, but not on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Rails / Mongoid app with the following relationships:

```
class CaseType
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :case_type_field_sets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :case_type_field_sets, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:description].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  field :description, type: String
end


class CaseTypeFieldSet
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :field_definitions
  embedded_in :case_type
  field :description, type: String
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :field_definitions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:description].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end


class FieldDefinition
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :description, type: String # what we use to render the UI
  embedded_in :case_type_field_set
end
```

All of these are updated using the case_types_controller, and all params are allowed:

```
def case_type_params
  params.require(:case_type).permit(:description, 
      :case_type_field_sets, case_type_field_sets_attributes: 
        [:id, :description, :_destroy, field_definitions_attributes: 
        [:id, :description, :_destroy]])
end
```

If I create a new case_type, then add a new case_type_field_set to it, then add a new field_definition to the case_type_field_set, all in one action, it works fine. However, if I create a new case_type, then add a new case_type_field_set, then save it, then go back and edit it, then add a new field_definition to the case_type_field_set, it says it saves with no error, however when I go back to edit it, the newly added field_set is missing.  There is no error mentioned in the server log:

```
Started PATCH "/case_types/57b479f4a4610006beba7254" for ::1 at 2016-08-17 13:21:45 -0400
Processing by CaseTypesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xJnbp9gr8yyDamRZItfBPUDDX4qSoOQ/XIbGM0D8urW6UAYGuM5FIT1w8jLaBhSnEC7PF/KMAxfB6+HGCYoAiA==", "case_type"=>{"description"=>"case type 1", "case_type_field_sets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "description"=>"asdf", "field_definitions_attributes"=>{"1471454502151"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "description"=>"new fd 3"}}, "id"=>"57b49c24a4610006beba725c"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Case type", "id"=>"57b479f4a4610006beba7254"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | opencaseware_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"case_types", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57b479f4a4610006beba7254')}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | opencaseware_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0009080000000000001s
0.000413s
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/case_types
Completed 302 Found in 12ms
```

Any ideas as to why the new nested creation works but the update fails silently?

UPDATE, i'm noticing that when the original create is called, it triggers a mongo insert, but when i update an existing record with a new embed, it does not trigger an insert, in case this is helpful.

UPDATE - I am pretty sure the issue is exclusively due to the models.  In the console you can easily reproduce this, if you make a CaseType, a CaseTypeFieldSet, and a FieldDefinition, and << them and then cave the topmost parent, it all works.  However if you make a CaseType and a CaseTypeFieldSet, save the CaseType, then try to add a new FieldDefinition to the CaseTypeFieldSet, and then save the parent, the FieldSet is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to say that restarting the rails server fixed this.